Short story. Humans and machines have co-operated in peace and prosperity on Earth for hundreds of years. Aliens attack and begin slaughtering humans
I read this short story since 2010 but it seemed very old, maybe seventy years old from the language used.
Humans had invented robots and super intelligent computers. Neither the word robot nor computer was used, just the term machine.
On Earth people and machines co-operated in peace and prosperity. Machines provided everything people needed but people persued artificial contests and were not unhappy.
The population of Earth dwindled to two million contented humans.
A great many powerful extra-terrestrial aliens attacked Earth in spaceships.The aliens slaughtered any humans they encountered immediately. They were described as like insects with three eyes.
The aliens did not destroy the intelligent machines. They had no such non biological intelligence in their experience. They assumed all the machines were being controlled by humans.

"The Last Evolution", a 1932 short story by John W. Campbell, Jr. which was also the answer to this old question and this one, is available at Project Gutenberg. You may have read it in one of these compilations.
On Earth people and machines co-operated in peace and prosperity. Machines provided everything people needed but people persued artificial contests and were not unhappy.

It was 2538 years After the Year of the Son of Man. For six centuries mankind had been developing machines. The Ear-apparatus was discovered as early as seven hundred years before. The Eye came later, the Brain came much later. But by 2500, the machines had been developed to think, and act and work with perfect independence. Man lived on the products of the machine, and the machines lived to themselves very happily, and contentedly. Machines are designed to help and cooperate. It was easy to do the simple duties they needed to do that men might live well. And men had created them. Most of mankind were quite useless, for they lived in a world where no productive work was necessary. But games, athletic contests, adventure—these were the things they sought for their pleasure. Some of the poorer types of man gave themselves up wholly to pleasure and idleness—and to emotions. But man was a sturdy race, which had fought for existence through a million years, and the training of a million years does not slough quickly from any form of life, so their energies were bent to mock battles now, since real ones no longer existed.

The population of Earth dwindled to two million contented humans.

Up to the year 2100, the numbers of mankind had increased rapidly and continuously, but from that time on, there was a steady decrease. By 2500, their number was a scant two millions, out of a population that once totaled many hundreds of millions, and was close to ten billions in 2100.

A great many powerful extra-terrestrial aliens attacked Earth in spaceships.

Then came the Outsiders. Whence they came, neither machine nor man ever learned, save only that they came from beyond the outermost planet, from some other sun. Sirius—Alpha Centauri—perhaps! First a thin scoutline of a hundred great ships, mighty torpedoes of the void a thousand kilads in length, they came.

They were described as like insects with three eyes.

Strange life-forms were crawling about the ship, protected by flexible, transparent suits. Their bodies were short, and squat, four-limbed and evidently powerful. They, like insects, were equipped with a thick, durable exoskeleton, horny, brownish coating that covered arms and legs and head. Their eyes projected slightly, protected by horny protruding walls—eyes that were capable of movement in every direction—and there were three of them, set at equal distances apart.

The aliens did not destroy the intelligent machines. They had no such non biological intelligence in their experience. They assumed all the machines were being controlled by humans.

"You—machines—are far more intelligent than we even now, and capable of changing overnight, capable of infinite adaptation to circumstance; you live as readily on Pluto as on Mercury or Earth. Any place is a home-world to you. You can adapt yourselves to any condition. And—most dangerous to them—you can do it instantly. You are their most deadly enemies, and they realize it. They have no intelligent machines; probably they can conceive of none. When you attack them, they merely say 'The life-form of Earth is sending out controlled machines. We will find good machines we can use.' They do not conceive that those machines which they hope to use are attacking them.

